# I'm having trouble using 'success_url' with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

In **views** I have the following classes:

```py
class AddPersonView(CustomCreateView):
    template_name = "register/add.html"
    form_class = PersonForm
    model = Person
    obj = Person.objects.all().count()
    if obj > 0:
        obj = Person.objects.last()
        success_url = reverse_lazy('register:edit_person_view', kwargs={'pk': obj.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddPersonView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


class EditPersonView(CustomUpdateView):
    template_name = "register/edit.html"
    form_class = PersonForm
    model = Person
    obj = Person.objects.all().count()
    if obj > 0:
        obj = Person.objects.last()
        success_url = reverse_lazy('register:edit_person_view', kwargs={'pk': obj.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditPersonView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

My intention is that when you submit `submit` on the person's registration page the new page is that person's edit page. But the way I'm using it, after adding or editing a person, the next page is opening with the `id` of the previous record.
For example, if I now register a `person` with id `12` and give `submit` the page I should open it would be `mysite.com/register/edit/12`, but it is opening `mysite.com/register/edit/11`.

I have tried to do the following: Instead of using the variable `sucess_url`, I used this function in both classes:

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('register:edit_person_view', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs('pk')})
```

However, by giving `submit` to the page I get this error:

```
TypeError at /register/edit/12/
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)
```

What is the correct way for the next page to be the edit page of the object I'm adding / editing?

**EDIT**

Doing some perceived tests that a `get_success_url` function is not working, because when it uses the same form, with a `success_url` variable, when editing a person and giving submit I am redirected to a new page for a new registration.

```py
class EditPersonView(CustomUpdateView):
    template_name = "register/edit.html"
    form_class = PersonForm
    model = Person
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register:add_person_view')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditPersonView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

But when using the function:

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('register:add_person_view')
```

I get the same error

```
TypeError at /register/edit/12/
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)
```

What is wrong so that the `get_success_url` function is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your out-by-one error is because `Person.objects.last()` is called when the create view is instantiated, which is *before* the new Person is created.

For get_success_url try this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('register:edit_person_view', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: I still get the same error: `TypeError at /register/edit/12/
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception (Reverse for 'None' not found. 'None' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)`